# Chrome Extension: How to refresh a tab based on its title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is how I refresh all chrome tabs in my chrome extension.

```
chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, function(tabs) {
for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {url: tabs[i].url});
}});
```

I don't want to refresh all tabs, I just want to refresh a single tab that has a word 'Inbox' in its title.

Can someone help adjusting my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the tab have Inbox is in the title.

```
chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, function(tabs)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
    {
        if(tabs[i].title.indexOf("Inbox") != -1)
            chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {url: tabs[i].url});
    }
});
```

And in case where you are sure you only have one tab with that title, you can break to save a (very) litle time of exection :

```
chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, function(tabs)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
    {
        if(tabs[i].title.indexOf("Inbox") != -1)
        {
            chrome.tabs.update(tabs[i].id, {url: tabs[i].url});
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You rock big time! This is exactly the solution I was looking for, worked like a charm.